# Jquery: highlight on mouse over doesn't work on certain pages

Tags: jquery

Testing this jquery code on external sites (loaded via proxy to bypass Single Origin Policy), it appears that there are certain sites where upon mouseover the expected red boarder line do not appear. How can I make sure that the red border line appears upon mouse over always on top of every thing else ? It could be that the certain site in which the highlighting upon mouseover does not appear, z-index or some other weirdness could be causing this problem, yet there are no javascript error presented....

```
$(document)
    .mouseover(function(event) {  
        if ($(event.target).parents('#myunique').length){ 
            event.preventDefault();
        }else{ 
        $(event.target).addClass('myoutlineElement');
        }
    })
    .mouseout(function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).parents('#myunique').length){  
            event.preventDefault();
        }else{      
        $(event.target).removeClass('myoutlineElement');  
        }
    })
```

Comment: I think we would need to see an example site?  Could existing `mouseover()` events on those pages be causing issues?

Comment: that's certainly a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouseover/out does not work ? or the border does not get applied.

Try debugging `console.log(event.target);` with firebug, to check if the event gets fired or not.

Also keep in mind, that if elements have defined border styling through the `style` attribute (`style="border:...;"`) then the class will not override it, as the style attribute is more specific.

Unless you use the `!important` directive, as [@aendrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281697/jquery-highlight-on-mouse-over-doesnt-work-on-certain-pages/4281747#4281747) mentions in his answer.

Comment: it does seem to be firing but no css changes can be seen. in some cases there exists already class attribute value. so even mouseover doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Where you define .myoutlineElement's CSS, you could try adding a z-index declaration like:

```
... z-index: 99 !important;
```

Comment: adding or increasing z-index doesn't seem to be fixing this error.